# How to extend Story type?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm writing a story for one of my components. Problem is that it accepts `style` object as a prop. Inside I have multiple options:

```
interface ColorProps{
  default?: string;
  hover?: string;
  active?: string;
}

interface StyleProps{
  iconColor: ColorProps;
  backgroundColor: ColorProps;
  borderColor: ColorProps;
}
```

How to handle these kind of props using Storybook? I thought that I'll just declare `args` that make sense, so that each of them can be individually changed and then combine them in one object.
I tried:

```
import type {Meta, StoryObj} from '@storybook/react';
import IconButton from '../IconButton';

const meta: Meta<typeof IconButton> = {
  title: 'Buttons/Icon',
  component: IconButton,
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof IconButton>;

export const Default: Story = {
  render: (args) => {
    return (
      <IconButton
        style={{
          iconColor: {
            default: args.defaultIconColor,
            hover: args.hoverIconColor,
            active: args.activeIconColor,
          },
          backgroundColor: {
            default: args.defaultBackgroundColor,
            hover: args.hoverBackgroundColor,
            active: args.activeBackgroundColor,
          },
          borderColor: {
            default: args.defaultBorderColor,
            hover: args.hoverBorderColor,
            active: args.activeBorderColor,
          },
        }}
      />
    );
  },
  argTypes:{
    defaultIconColor:{
        control: 'color'
    }
  },
  args: {
    defaultIconColor: '#a8eb34',
  }
};
```

I get error saying that `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'defaultIconColor' does not exist in type 'Partial<ArgTypes<Props>>'.`, which makes sense, since it's not `IconButton` prop. But then how to handle objects as props inside Storybook? I might create individual type for `Story`, but not sure if it's a right path to take.